# Force creating new record for a lookup field in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In a N:1 relationship where I have a lookup field on the N side, is there a way to force the user to create new record instead of selecting one from the lookup view?

Essentially, I have a 1:1 relationship which I'm trying to implement using N:1 and don't want the user to link an existing record that's already linked.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the `Add Existing` button from the ribbon.

The [Ribbon Editor](http://crmvisualribbonedit.codeplex.com/) is well worth a download (editing the ribbons is still unnecessarily fiddly for me)

But you can also try [one of the several blogs on the subject](http://mscrmshop.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/step-by-step-hiding-add-existing-button.html)

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not working with a sub-grid. I have a lookup field.

Answer (score 0):

You could always create a new View and set it to the lookup.
(Don't forget to disable the view selection in the entity form)

In the view's filter criteria, you could look for those with "Created on" in "the last x hour" where x can be 1.

Comment: Another way could be to set disabled the lookup and add a custom webRessource. 
The webRessource(HTML) could be a button that open a new Entity and when you save the entity, you set its values in the lookup `<lookupname>.setValue([{ id: <id>, name: <name>, typename: <logicalName>}])`

The only problem is that I have no idea how to do this in supported way.